# Export Org-Mode Timesheet Data?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, csv

I've taken to using org-mode for keeping track of my open tasks each week, notes on various tasks, and to generate a LaTeX formatted report at the end of each week that breaks down my time by task and subtask per day. This has all been great. I'm curious, however, if there's not some way to export this timesheet data for analysis in some other system or import into a holistic database. I like to use historical task data for estimates and the current structure makes it hard to aggregate my data and analyze it.

I was wondering if there was some way to export my logbook entries into something like a CSV file so I can import it into Excel or write a Python script to analyze it or something. If it might make this export easier, I'm considering moving from a 1 file per week organizational structure to one long running file per project. This should at least keep related log entries in physical proximity and more likely to be logged under the same entries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a relatively new package called [org-clock-csv](https://github.com/atheriel/org-clock-csv) that does exactly this.

I'm not sure why you'd want to use anything other than org-mode to analyze the data though... ;-)

Comment: The explanations on the *github* page are very poor. It can be improved with ease. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: Yeah; the README documentation is a little thin, but the package has good docstrings and is easy to follow.  I'm sure (documentation) PR's are welcome ;-)